# asReversed() vs reversed() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I noticed that Kotlin has two built in methods [reversed()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html) and  [asReversed()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html)

Is there any difference between these two? or are they essentially just doing the exact same thing?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Kotlin, both reversed and asReversed have their own unique functions.

The **Reverse** function returns a list with elements in reversed: order.

[Reversed Function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html)

Whereas, the **asReversed** function returns a reversed read-only view of the original List i.e., all changes made in the original list will be reflected in the reversed one.

[asReversed Function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html)

**The difference between the two are that once the asReversed() function has been used, any changes in the original list will be reflected in the reversed list as well. 
But the same doesn't hold valid or true when the reversed() function is being used. It's merely used to reverse a list.**

Example:

```
    val list = mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    val asReversed = list.asReversed()
    val reversed   = list.reversed()

    println("Original list: $list")
    println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
    println("reversed:      $reversed")

    list[0] = 10

    println("Original list: $list")
    println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
    println("reversed:      $reversed")
```

Outputs

```
Original list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
Original list: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vc7NCsIwDAfw8/oUYezQQpHOj8vANxAGXsVDxU6KXZW020V89triRucLeAoJv/yT@8MbbUPoBgu91JYyeBFSjNKA0c7DHvrBy4tRh9i1HRUcag5rDhsOWw47NmHpjmpU6NQ1rqTNVZ5Q9jU4C5gNZkGKJ2rrjaVli/qm7fRBA1UqJVuAHN3ELKhy/8NwiSLDjEiRQk/iHD@pxb@Pv0P4AA)

Comment: I already linked both those doc pages in the question, I was able to read them myself - I am still just confused to what the actual difference is... They both seem to just return a reversed list of the original list as an immutable `List` object.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't brief about the major difference initially. It's been added to my answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense

Comment: edited your answer to add an example snippet of the different behaviour

Answer (score 3):

As per the document

**1. reversed()**

It only returns a list **(List<>)** with elements in reversed order.

There are **multiple definitions of this extension** on different Objects like Array, List, etc.

Example of extension on

**Array<>**

```
/**
 * Returns a list with elements in reversed order.
 */
public fun <T> Array<out T>.reversed(): List<T> {
    if (isEmpty()) return emptyList()
    val list = toMutableList()
    list.reverse()
    return list
}
```

**List<>**

```
/**
 * Returns a list with elements in reversed order.
 */
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.reversed(): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection && size <= 1) return toList()
    val list = toMutableList()
    list.reverse()
    return list
}
```

**2. asReversed()**

It is only applicable to **List<>** and returns a reversed read-only view of the original List. All changes made in the original list will be reflected in the reversed one.

Comment: I seem to be able to call reversed on List's as well, I don't think it is only for arrays - does list inherit arrays?

Comment: These both **array and list** come under the package of kotlin collections. So that's why you can make the same extension call to list as well as on array.