# Is asReversed() essentially reversed() for List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

As stated in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57115894/3286489, the `asReversed()` will generate a reversed list, that value will be changed if the original list has changed its element within.

```
    val list = mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val asReversed = list.asReversed()
    val reversed   = list.reversed()
    println("Original list: $list")
    println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
    println("reversed:      $reversed")

    list[0] = 10

    println("Original list: $list")
    println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
    println("reversed:      $reversed")
```

Outputs

```
Original list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
Original list: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

To me, that means only if the original list is a `MutableList` then it can change it's value within.

However, if the original List is an immutable `List`, it's value cannot be changed, this essentially make `asReversed()` and `reversed()` has not distinct difference on it, right?

i.e.

```
    val list = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val asReversed = list.asReversed() // This is the same as below?
    val reversed   = list.reversed()   // This is the same as above?
```

Did I miss any scenario they are still different?

**Updated**
I even change what it contains as `mutableList`

```
     val list = listOf(
            mutableListOf(1), 
            mutableListOf(2), 
            mutableListOf(3), 
            mutableListOf(4), 
            mutableListOf(5), 
            mutableListOf(6))
        val asReversed = list.asReversed()
        val reversed   = list.reversed()
        println("Original list: $list")
        println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
        println("reversed:      $reversed")

        list[0][0] = 10

        println("Original list: $list")
        println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
        println("reversed:      $reversed")
```

Output

```
Original list: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
asReversed:    [[6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [1]]
reversed:      [[6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [1]]
Original list: [[5], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
asReversed:    [[6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [10]]
reversed:      [[6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [10]]
```

This will change for both `asReversed` and `reversed` result

Comment: Probably the most noticable difference is that [reversed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html) defined for both arrays and iterables and returns list. While [asReversed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html) is only defined for List and MutableList which returns their respective types.

Comment: Ya, having it on `MutableList` makes sense. But I'm still trying to figure out why it has to be for `List`... since `List`s element can't be changed.

Comment: just because you have a `List` doesn't mean, that it can't change ;-) the `asReversed` is just a view on the list... it always contains a reference to the original list... that means, if the original list changes (regardless how), it will reflect those changes in the `asReversed` case... but you would always get a new list in the `reversed`-case... and just because you operate with a readonly list, doesn't mean, that its content doesn't change... you could cast it to the original or only a readonly view is passed to a function, but the actual list is mutable...

Comment: @Roland, it would be great if you could provide an example of how to change the element of `List`, that would help.

Comment: Regarding your update: well... I think you fooled yourself because you used a list in list approach. Note that the `reversed` constructed you an independent list of the contents of the original list, which are lists... so you end up having the same references in your new list, which are also in the original list... and then you adapt a list that was referenced, so clearly that must be adapted in all lists, regardless whether `asReversed` or `reversed` is used... you could have even called `toList()` additionally and your changes would be reflected...

Comment: The `(list as ArrayList).remove(2)` will crash. It can't happen.

Comment: As for the updated, I was hoping that was I change the would change the `asReversed`  but not the `reversed`. Unfortunately, both changed :(

Comment: sorry... `listOf`uses the `Arrays$ArrayList`... so `remove` will not work... my mistake... you could however do the following: `(list as MutableList).set(2, /* whatever */)`

Comment: regarding your last comment...  did my answer explain you why it changed both lists? if not, let me know... your updated part only has to do with references... less with `reversed`/`asReversed`...

Comment: I would not rely on `(list as MutableList).set` being safe. The underlying implementation used by `listOf` could change in the future. No promises whatsoever are made that you can even cast it to `MutableList` safely.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are completely right.. it's an implementation detail, that just shows that for now even that immutable or readonly list is actually mutable... actually I deleted the comment mentioning that it is an implementation detail, because it wasn't correct regarding the `ArrayList`-cast... for this example however I think it's not that important which kind of approach you actually use to show that a `List` could still be mutated... it's just important that `asReversed` always contains a bidirectional connection to the original list, whereas `reversed` gives you new independent lists...

Answer (score 4):

The most important difference between the two is, that `asReversed` is always just a view on the original list. That means, if you alter the original list, the result of `asReversed` will always contain all the updated information. In the end it's just a view.

`reversed` however always gives you a new disconnected list of the original list. Note however that when you deal with object references within the original list (like lists in a list or other kind of objects that are referenceable) then you will see all the adaptations of the original object of that list also adapted in the reversed ones, regardless of whether you used `reversed` or `asReversed`.

Regarding your update it is unfortunate you used such a list that contains references. With your original list however the difference becomes much clearer:

```
val asReversed = list.asReversed()
val reversed = list.reversed()

fun printAll(msg : String) {
  println(msg)
  println("Original list: $list")
  println("asReversed:    $asReversed")
  println("reversed:      $reversed")
}
printAll("Initial ----")

list as MutableList
list[2] = 1000
printAll("mutating original list ----")

reversed as MutableList
reversed[4] = 3000
printAll("mutating reversed list ----")
```

As `asReversed` returns you a `ReversedListReadOnly`-type, you can't easily cast it to a `MutableList`, but if it would be possible, the changes in `asReversed` would be reflected in the original list, but not in the `reversed`. The output of the above is the following:

```
Initial ----
Original list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
mutating original list ----
Original list: [0, 1, 1000, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 1000, 1, 0]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
mutating reversed list ----
Original list: [0, 1, 1000, 3, 4, 5]
asReversed:    [5, 4, 3, 1000, 1, 0]
reversed:      [5, 4, 3, 2, 3000, 0]
```

As you can see: the changes are nicely reflected in the original and the `asReversed`-list, but changes in the `reversed` are not reflected and also the reversed one will not contain the original list adaptations.

So, yes, you probably missed that scenario... the lists (`reversed` and `asReversed`) aren't equal, not even, if you have a readonly view as input, as noone can guarantee you that the list isn't altered... neither the original nor the `asReversed` one.

Comment: Agree with your answer, but it is answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115611/asreversed-vs-reversed-in-kotlin question instead of mine.

Comment: Cool, I think casting that to `Mutable` is one way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @Elye you cannot cast it to MutableList check the snippet https://pl.kotl.in/71MkYZ0Mc

Comment: @Animesh Sahu, I tested using Android Studio, and Roland's code works.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu note that `add` and `remove` will not work on a `Arrays$ArrayList`... and note that it isn't a `java.util.ArrayList`...

Answer (score 2):

To add to other answers, this is an example of a general method-naming convention in Kotlin (and, to an extent in Java):

- `toNoun()` methods *convert* an object into a new form that's independent of the original.
- `asNoun()` methods return a *view* onto the existing object; changes in that will be reflected in the view and (if appropriate) vice versa.
- `verb()` methods mutate the object directly (and don't return anything).
- `verbed()` methods return a mutated *copy* of the object, leaving the original unchanged.

This question provides examples of two of those cases.

These conventions are very lightweight, read well, and are used fairly consistently.  After you've seen a few, you know almost instinctively how a method will behave!

(It's not universal, though; for example, `map()` is a verb, but doesn't mutate its receiver.  However, methods like `map()` and `filter()` long pre-date Kotlin, and so it's arguably better to stick to well-known existing names like that.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Their difference actually amazed me!

Okay so by browsing the std-lib this is what I've found.

The `reversed` function actually **creates a copy** of whatever the Iterable is as a MutableList and **reverses the list "really"** and then returns it.

```kotlin
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.reversed(): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection && size <= 1) return toList()
    val list = toMutableList()
    list.reverse()
    return list
}
```

**While when you call the asReversed(), it doesn't create a new list "by copying the elements".**

It just creates an implementation of an Abstract list with delegation to the real list, and overriding the getter.

```kotlin
public fun <T> List<T>.asReversed(): List<T> = ReversedListReadOnly(this)

private open class ReversedListReadOnly<out T>(private val delegate: List<T>) : AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size: Int get() = delegate.size
    override fun get(index: Int): T = delegate[reverseElementIndex(index)]
}
```

So there's no overhead, since the list is immutable there is no need to touch any other part, neither need to copy the list i.e. no need for creating a new one and allocate its memory. It is simplified and just uses the original list.

Comment: In terms of implementation, that's right. But in practically, they both (`reversed` and `asReversed`) are same for List, right?

Comment: @Elye, no in case of `reversed` which is defined for all Array and Iterable types, it creates a new object of ArrayList while `asReversed` doesn't. as also pointed by answer by Roland `reversed however always gives you a new disconnected list of the original list.`

Comment: Agree with your answer, but it is answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115611/asreversed-vs-reversed-in-kotlin question instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Found this example here https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html

```
        val original = mutableListOf('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
        val originalReadOnly = original as List<Char>
        val reversedA = originalReadOnly.asReversed()
        val reversedB = originalReadOnly.reversed()

        println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e]
        println(reversedA) // [e, d, c, b, a]
        println(reversedB)

        // changing the original list affects its reversed view
        original.add('f')
        println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
        println(reversedA) // [f, e, d, c, b, a]
        println(reversedB) // [e, d, c, b, a]

        original[original.lastIndex] = 'z'
        println(original) // [a, b, c, d, e, z]
        println(reversedA) // [z, e, d, c, b, a]
        println(reversedB)  // [e, d, c, b, a]
```

It does show that a `List` can still be changed if it was originally from a `MutableList`, where we change the `MutableList`. Hence that makes `asReversed()` is still different from `reversed()` in this case, since there's a way to change the `List` by changing the original `MutableList`

Comment: Tbh this is a great example for explaining the difference, but a real List<T> created from listOf() can never be converted into a MutableList or a ArrayList<T>. check: https://pl.kotl.in/71MkYZ0Mc

Comment: @Aminesh Sahu, in my example I didn't convert List to MutableList, but the other way around. The example code is taken from Kotlin Collection document, and tested working.

Comment: It's safe to upcast MutableList to List. Unsafe to downcast List to MutableList. IMO, you should not have to design around the risk of improper downcasting (an abuse of reflection), but this example shows why you can't assume these two implementations will always return the same data (so long as you aren't locally controlling the original list of data).