# How to reverse an ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to reverse an ArrayList using reversed method but its return type is List. I want ArrayList as return type as I have to pass the ArrayList into the RecyclerView Adapter

Comment: This may be kind of off-topic, but does this `ArrayList` requirement originate from Android API or you did parameterize some generic type with `ArrayList`? I ask because normally we should not require `ArrayList` specifically as this creates problems, including that one here. For some reasons many developers tend to use `ArrayList` everywhere instead of just `List`/`MutableList`, but it is surprising to me that Android API does this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `reverse()` on it. There is no return type (other than Unit) because it modifies the original list. Maybe you were looking at `reversed()` which creates a reversed copy of the list.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61732304/506796) has some helpful information on how to interpret the meaning of the English grammar used in standard library collection functions.