# Firebase -What is the Kotlin version of Swift's snapshot.children.allObjects

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm an iOS dev and I'm just getting into Kotlin. I have the following code that works in Swift `snapshot.children.allObjects`, what is the Kotlin version of it?

Swift

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    guard let firstChild = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
    print(firstChild.key)

    let arr = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    let reversedArr = arr.reversed()

    for child in reversedArr {
        let someId = child.key
        print(someId)
    }
})
```

Kotlin

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) { }
})
```

Comment: See the Kotlin code sample in the documentation on [listening for a value event on a list of nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allObjects` is a member of the [`NSEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsenumerator) from Foundation, so of course Kotlin wouldn't have it. It iterates through the entire collection and gives you an array.

The Kotlin version of `children` returns an `Iterator<DataSnapshot>`. `Iterator` doesn't have anything similar that gives you a `List<DataSnapshot>` or `Array<DataSnapshot>`, but it does have [`asSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/as-sequence.html), which is a lazy sequence of the remaining contents of the iterator.

From there, you can then call `toList()` (like `allObjects`, this consumes the entire lazy sequence) after whatever intermediate operators you want to do.

It seems like you want to get the snapshots in reverse order? That would be:

```kotlin
val reversed = snapshot.children.asSequence().toList().asReversed()
for (child in reversed) {
    println(child.key)
}
```

Note that you should use [`asReversed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html), instead of [`reversed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html). The latter creates a new list, instead of just a reversed "view" of the original list. See also: [asReversed() vs reversed() in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57115611/5133585)

Using `asReversed` is more similar to the behaviour of Swift's [`reversed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/reversed()), which returns `ReversedCollection<[DataSnapshot]>`.

Side note: in the beginning of the code, you accessed `allObjects` just to check if there is any children in the snapshot. That is rather a waste. `DataSnapshot` has a dedicated `hasChildren()` method (in both Kotlin and Swift) for this purpose.

Comment: `snapshot.asSequence()` didn't work for me because `asSequence()` kept coming up as red. I was able to use `sequenceOf(snapshot).toList()`. You led me where I needed to go, thanks! Good explanation too :)

Comment: @LanceSamaria Ah I meant `snapshot.children.asSequence()`. I'm surprised `sequenceOf(snapshot)` also worked :)